# find and replace in all occurences of div text using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

Below is my screenshot.

[image]

This is the text inside my div.I want to replace "" as "-" and "" as "-" in all occurances inside div and then pass in ajax using jquery because as like this we cannot store in database.I tried with

```
var para = $('#list_id');

   var drag_words_paragraph = para.html(para.html().replace(new RegExp("<div class="fancy" draggable="true">","</div>"),"-"));
```

But it is not replace all occurance correctly.Please anyone help me to get out of this issue.

Comment: you want to replace "" as "-" and "" as "-"? which is not clear, can you explain how you want the text output by typing it as an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure I understand your question. But if your trying to replace all the " with - to save in your database you could you use Javascripts replace (g will include a global replace).

```
var para = $('#list_id');
var drag_words_paragraph = para.html();
var result = drag_words_paragraph.replace(/"/g, "-");
```